# Centers of Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

https://binyamini.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/last-practice.pdf

Q7 Why are there 3 centers A, B, C?

I am not sure how there can be 3 centers, I thought the idea was to make the

F(Z) plane centering at the origin.

Comment: Can someone please help me understand this principle?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 centers because the task master wanted you to explore 3 centers. The question is for the winding number counts of $f(z)-A$, $f(z)-B$ and $f(z)-C$ and the conclusions according to Rouche theorem on the number of roots and  poles.